# Запрет поворота экрана

Tags: jquery, mobile, css, javascript

Приветствую Всех!

Как можно запретить поворот экрана с помощью Jquery Mobile или простой CSS, JS или PhoneGap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщето можно получить эту информацию, вот статья: [Вьюпорты на мобильных](http://quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html) правда она английском а вот примерный перевод [Сказ о двух вьюпортах](http://www.beskrovnyy.com/verstka/skaz-o-dvux-vyuportax-chast-pervaya/) суть в срабатывании события `window.onresize` и изменении размера для тега `<HTML>`

Answer (score 1):

Нет. За поворот экрана отвечает ОС телефона, к которой доступ получить невозможно

Comment: я имею ввиду, чтобы сам контент не переворачивался.

Comment: Я понял. Ты  не сможешь считать информацию о наклоне телефона с акселерометра

Comment: Почему это? Если говорить о Phonegap, то в javascript встраиваются объекты и доступ через них к возможностям девайса. там и акселерометр и камера и gps и проч. [PhoneGap orientation example][1]

Другое дело запретить...

[1]:http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/4/PhoneGap-Orientation-Example

Answer (score 0):

```css
#rotate-device {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(/path to img/rotate.png);
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) and (min-device-width: 320px) and (orientation: landscape){
 #rotate-device {
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate-device"></div>
```