# Jquery высота экрана в реальном времени

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли фишечка, которая определяла бы высоту экрана в реальном времени?

есть вот такая тема

```
$(window).height()
```

но она определяет при загрузке стр, а нужно чтобы в реальном времени?! Т.е. при любом изменении размеров окна, без перезагрузки стр!

Comment: событие есть resize называется.

Comment: а можно дать пример, я только учусь?! ((
допустим у меня есть div, у которого свойство display:fixed, при уменьшении окна до 800px, оно должно становиться display:absolute

Comment: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Обработчик_или_источник_события_resize
p.s. better use pure js

Comment: http://jsbin.com/esolay/3/

Comment: не работает ваша штука

Comment: как это не работает, какой браузер ?

Comment: Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14

Comment: у меня работает: 

    Opera:
    Версия: 12.14 
    Сборка: 1738 
    Платформа: Linux 
    Система: x86_64, 3.2.0-4-rt-amd64

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries должно и у вас работать, может с браузером что-то не в  порядке

Comment: действительно, работает. либо глюк, либо я криво смотрел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
          alert( $(window).height() );
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я уже отвечал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/99300/jquery-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Можно получить эту информацию, вот статья: [Вьюпорты на мобильных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/99300/jquery-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) правда она английском а вот примерный перевод [Сказ о двух вьюпортах][2] суть в срабатывании события `window.onresize` и изменении размера для тега `<HTML>`
Например можно сделать так:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;        
}
```